# convert list into data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert a list into a data frame with two columns.

The list comes from the next code,

```
test <- sapply(data_frame_1, table)
```

each column of data_frame_1 has 70 rows with two values "1" and "2", so I count the times of each value in each column, the above code give me an output like this:

```
test["1_hypothetical_protein.faa"]
```

```
$`1_hypothetical_protein.faa`

 1  2 
69  1
```

I want a data frame with two columns "1" and "2" like the next:

```
                               1 2 
1_hypothetical_protein.faa     1 69
```

I have tried with the next options

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(test, as.data.frame))
```

and it yields

```
                                 Var1 Freq
1_hypothetical_protein.faa.1        1   69
1_hypothetical_protein.faa.2        2    1
```

I also have tried with

```
new_df <- data.frame(t(data.frame(test)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without having to cast to data frame before binding, i.e.

```
l1 <- list(iris, iris)

do.call(rbind, lapply(l1, function(i) table(i$Species)))
#     setosa versicolor virginica
#[1,]     50         50        50
#[2,]     50         50        50
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this in the tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat <- list(iris, iris)
names(dat) <- c("iris_first", "iris_second")

lapply(dat, function(x) x %>%
         group_by(Species) %>%
         summarise(count = n())) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "id") %>%
  spread(Species, count)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  id          setosa versicolor virginica
  <chr>        <int>      <int>     <int>
1 iris_first      50         50        50
2 iris_second     50         50        50
```